# div on.click event doesn't work when i am in chrome mobile version

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome

I have the following div element in jquery:

```
this.$flipPages.find( '.box' ).on( 'click.flips', function( event ) {

    var $box            = $(this),
    $boxClose       = $( '<span class="box-close">close</span>' ),
    transitionProp  = {
        speed           : 450,
        timingfunction  : 'linear'
    },
    $overlay        = $( '<div class="overlay">close</div>' ).css( {
                        'z-index'               : 9998,
                        '-webkit-transition'    : 'opacity ' + transitionProp.speed + 'ms ' + transitionProp.timingfunction,
                        '-moz-transition'       : 'opacity ' + transitionProp.speed + 'ms ' + transitionProp.timingfunction
                    } ).prependTo( $( 'body' ) ),
    prop            = {
        width   : $box.outerWidth(true),
        height  : $box.outerHeight(true),
        left    : $box.offset().left,
        top     : $box.offset().top
    },
    $placeholder    = $box.clone().css( {
        'position'          : 'absolute',
        'width'             : prop.width,
        'height'            : prop.height,
        'left'              : prop.left,
        'top'               : prop.top,
        'zIndex'            : 9999,
        'overflow-y'        : 'auto',
        '-webkit-transition': 'all ' + transitionProp.speed + 'ms ' + transitionProp.timingfunction,
        '-moz-transition': 'all ' + transitionProp.speed + 'ms ' + transitionProp.timingfunction
    } )
    .insertAfter( $overlay )
    .end()
    .append( $boxClose.on( 'click.flips', function( event ) {

        $overlay.css( 'opacity', 0 );

        $placeholder.children().hide().end().removeClass( 'box-expanded' ).css( {
            width           : _self.windowProp.width,
            height          : _self.windowProp.height,
            'overflow-y'    : 'hidden'
        } );

        setTimeout( function() {
            $placeholder.css( {
                left    : prop.left,
                top     : prop.top,
                width   : prop.width,
                height  : prop.height,
                '-webkit-transition'    : 'all ' + transitionProp.speed + 'ms ' + transitionProp.timingfunction,
                '-moz-transition'   : 'all ' + transitionProp.speed + 'ms ' + transitionProp.timingfunction
            });
        }, 0 );

        }) ).children().hide().end()
            .on( 'webkitTransitionEnd.flips transitionend.flips OTransitionEnd.flips', function( event ) {

            if( $( event.target ).hasClass( 'box-expanded' ) ) { // expanding

                $(this).css( {
                    width   : '100%',
                    height  : '100%',
                    '-webkit-transition' : 'none',
                    '-moz-transition' : 'none'
                } ).children().fadeIn();

            }
            else { // collapsing

                $overlay.remove();
                $(this).remove();

            }

    });

    setTimeout( function() {

        $overlay.css( {
            opacity : 1
        } );

        $placeholder.addClass( 'box-expanded' ).css( {
            left    : 0,
            top     : 0,
            width   : _self.windowProp.width,
            height  : _self.windowProp.height
        });

    }, 0 );

} );
```

this .box is a div that has content and it is clickable, although this works in desktop and laptop version of chrome it does not in the mobile chrome version. It works on safari android version. I use Kinetic and i heard there are some tweaks i have to do when using it to make it work on chrome for mobile.

Is there any reason this doesnt work on chrome mobile?

EDIT:

I have added a alert inside this function and when i am using chrome for desktop it prints, if i am using chrome mobile it never alerts anything. it is not being called.

Comment: You need to return false from the onclick function to make it work. If it doesn't work check my answer. it may work probably

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you are searching for is a tap event for mobiles and click event for desktops
this will probably work:

```
this.$flipPages.find( '.box' ).on( 'touchend click.flips', function( event ) {
   ...
});
```

Answer (score -1):

This piece of code may make it work in mobile . this is a mocking the mouse event in mobile

```
if(BrowserDetect.browser.indexOf("Chrome") != -1) {
    var fireOnThis = document.getElementById("idofelementtobeclicked");
    var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    evObj.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window, 0, 0, 345, 7, 220, false, false, true, false, 0, null);
    fireOnThis.dispatchEvent(evObj);
    return true;
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: in which function should i place this? the return false didnt work. u say return true but u never say where and how i should place this block of code

Comment: Khaleel, while you may be onto something here you need to provide more of an explanation rather than just dumping this code here. What's it doing, clearly stated? How is it used?